# QGsComposerLabel set text

Tags: pyqgis

I am building a composition with map, legend... I want to add a paragraph (text) to the composition but the text only recognize one word. What I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
text = QgsComposerLabel(myComposition)
text.setText("Prognostico" + "\n" + "Coordinate System: ETRS89 PTTM06" + '\n' + str(self.pr))
text.setFont(QFont("Cambria",15, QFont.Bold))
text.setItemPosition(328.2, 72.3, 87.7,102.3)
text.adjustSizeToText()
#title.setFrameEnabled(True)
myComposition.addItem(text)
```

In this example only Prognostico word is showed in the layout. Why the rest doesn't appears?

Answer (score 3):

I modified slightly your code to include 'setMargin' method (with a negative margin) and for adapting to my own composition object parameters.

```
pr = 'test'
text = QgsComposerLabel(c)
text.setText("Prognostico" + "\n" + "Coordinate System: ETRS89 PTTM06" + '\n' + str(pr))
text.setFont(QFont("Cambria",15, QFont.Bold))
text.setItemPosition(40, 40, True)
text.adjustSizeToText()
#text.setFrameEnabled(True)
text.setMargin(-6)
c.addItem(text)
```

My code worked (where 'test' it would be your **self.pr** string) and it produced the next result:

[image]

You should try out with your parameters to find out the best margin. I hope that it helps.